# Fix a warning activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I get a warning from compiler when I build my Android application.

```
activity com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode 
was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
```

And it is my current dependency of firebase.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
```

Do you know how to fix the warning?

Answer (score 10):

Please try to enter this code in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...>

<activity
    android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
    tools:replace="android:launchMode"
    android:launchMode="standard" />
...
```

Comment: answering your own question? does this solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, I did, because I found the answer.

Comment: Since it solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as Solved. It's perfectly legit to do that with your own answers, and it helps others see that it works. :-)

Comment: Some more background, references would have been nice to have.

Comment: Do not use this solution if you are using Firebase AuthUI, as it breaks the OAuth sign-in flow.  It's possible it will break other things too.

Comment: Do not use this solution. It breaks OAuth provider flows (checked with Apple sign in). There is also nothing in the Firebase guides/docs requiring its use.

Comment: this moved the problem but did not solve it. any further details to debug??

Answer (score -1):

```
The error can also be due to the MultiDex in this case change your app build.gradle as follow
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
if you do not override the Application class, change Application tag as such in the Manifest File
<application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
```